# Some strange users

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, firefox, security, users

something going wrong here. 
[Here is my htop screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jKnD.png)
I didn't launch any firefox or firefox plugins. In fact I've just deleted firefox at all.

Here is my /etc/passwd

```
$ cat /etc/passwd
...
guest-v2ZwkB:x:119:127:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-v2ZwkB:/bin/bash
guest-CoeJOG:x:120:128:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-CoeJOG:/bin/bash
guest-GBapg4:x:121:129:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-GBapg4:/bin/bash
guest-oqAb2e:x:122:130:Guest,,,:/tmp/guest-oqAb2e:/bin/bash
```

Who the hell is guest-* ? I didn't create those users.

Here is w cmd output

```
$ w
 03:06:54 up 12:50,  6 users,  load average: 3,45, 3,29, 2,82
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
m0x35    :0       :0               Сб.14   ?xdm?   9:45m  0.11s init --user
m0x35    pts/6    :0.0             Сб.14    0.00s  0.11s  0.01s w
guest-v2 :1       :1               17:52   ?xdm?   9:45m  0.09s init --user
guest-Co :2       :2               18:04   ?xdm?   9:45m  0.09s init --user
guest-GB :3       :3               23:36   ?xdm?   9:45m  0.10s init --user
guest-oq :4       :4               23:58   ?xdm?   9:45m  0.08s init --user
```

What the hell is going on? I've been hacked? I have to worry about that?

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

I will be glad to provide additional information. Thanks.

`sudo netstat -natp` showed nothing special. Just some opened ports for nfs service, cupsd, dnsmasq. But two ports are binded for some other service and I can't get pid/programm name from the netstat.

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:44483           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

I've monitored my interface with tcpdump for about a minute - nothing strange.

**UPD:**

```
03:32:42.455320 IP le-in-f93.1e100.net.https > m0x35-pc.47065: tcp 727
03:32:42.455334 IP m0x35-pc.47065 > le-in-f93.1e100.net.https: tcp 0
03:32:42.455339 IP le-in-f93.1e100.net.https > m0x35-pc.47065: tcp 46
03:32:42.455662 IP m0x35-pc.47065 > le-in-f93.1e100.net.https: tcp 46
03:32:42.456394 IP m0x35-pc.63482 > 192.168.35.4.domain: UDP, length 47
03:32:42.456428 IP m0x35-pc.25024 > 192.168.35.4.domain: UDP, length 47
03:32:42.456453 IP m0x35-pc.20231 > 192.168.35.4.domain: UDP, length 47
03:32:42.463492 IP 192.168.35.4.domain > m0x35-pc.63482: UDP, length 314
03:32:42.463547 IP 192.168.35.4.domain > m0x35-pc.25024: UDP, length 246
03:32:42.463566 IP 192.168.35.4.domain > m0x35-pc.20231: UDP, length 314
03:32:42.463926 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 0
03:32:42.468759 IP lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https > m0x35-pc.39292: tcp 0
03:32:42.468802 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 0
03:32:42.468940 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 517
03:32:42.473731 IP lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https > m0x35-pc.39292: tcp 0
03:32:42.473899 IP lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https > m0x35-pc.39292: tcp 152
03:32:42.473913 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 0
03:32:42.474249 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 51
03:32:42.474523 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 157
03:32:42.474585 IP m0x35-pc.39292 > lj-in-f100.1e100.net.https: tcp 301
```

I've closed everything that can communicate (or supposed to) with the internet.
P.s. Seems like it's a google servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like yourself, or someone else who has access to your computer, logged in as a guest in the system.

You can delete these guest users with:

```
sudo deluser username
```

Like this:

```
sudo deluser guest-v2ZwkB
```

And you can disable the guest session editting the following file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf
```

Add the following line, save and close.

```
allow-guest=false
```

Comment: But if it is true those sessions are still running and I can login? Or am I wrong?

Comment: They might be running if the user did not performed a logoff.

Comment: Okay, but can I get into those sessions? I've tried to lock my session and enter as guest via lightdm, but new session was created.

Comment: I don't think you can join previous sessions. Just reboot your computer, they should be deleted automatically. If the users persist you can delete them manually. Also, Firefox is being executed by one of the guest users.

Comment: If so, than some more strange stuff. Why I can still see firefox running without any user mentioned. Especially /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer... I've closed firefox many hours ago, but it still there.

Comment: I don't see nothing wrong with this, the plugin-container handles the Flash content on Firefox.

Comment: Ok, don't know why htop didn't show the users. $ ps -ef | grep firefox
guest-v+  5559  4990 19 нояб.14 ?  02:01:46 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
guest-v+  5636  5559 57 нояб.14 ?  05:55:50 /usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so -greomni /usr/lib/firefox/omni.ja -appomni /usr/lib/firefox/browser/omni.ja -appdir /usr/lib/firefox/browser 5559 true plugin
guest-o+  8389  7743 58 нояб.14 ?  02:24:42 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox